# Unable to read json data to draw a graph

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, highcharts

I am new to jQuery and json. Trying to draw a graph with reference to the demo from 
 http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/

This graph uses data from a json file

http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?

this file directly started with data. But the json file that I want to use looks something like this

`{"name": {
    "text1": "on",
    "data": {
        [1147651200000,67.79],
    [1147737600000,64.98],
    [1147824000000,65.26],
    [1147910400000,63.18],
    [1147996800000,64.51],
    [1148256000000,63.38],
    [1148342400000,63.15],
    [1148428800000,63.34],
    [1148515200000,64.33],
    [1148601600000,63.55],
    [1148947200000,61.22],
    [1149033600000,59.77],
    }
}}`

could someone help me with this please

Comment: not valid json ...check here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: `Parse error on line 4:
...ata": {            [                11
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'`

Comment: replace the `{` with '[' in `data` part that will make your json valid

Comment: But what is your problem, because jsonp from url works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is invalid.

If your data property is an array, so you should use `[]` to denote the array.

I'm assuming that array is an array of arrays, so inside `[]`, it should have multiple `[]`s.

Like:

`[[x1,y1],[x2,y2]...]`

Try formatting your code sample as follows...

```
{
    "name": {
        "text1": "on",
        "data": [
            [
                1147651200000,
                67.79
            ],
            [
                1147651200000,
                67.79
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Use something like http://jsonlint.com/ to check your json's validity.

Comment: I didnot post the actual json. I am using an already existing json which I am not supposed show out. http://jsonlint.com/ says the json is valid. the problem is that my json looks like the one in http://json.org/example.html and my data array is in the place of "GlossEntry" and I dont know how to reach there

Comment: yourObj.glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry